# getting started with ROS Android: error in building rosjava_core

Tags: ros, rosjava-core, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Trying to use rosAndroid with Fuerte.  As far as I can tell, I have to first install and build rosjava_core, then rosjava_android, then I can follow the tutorial here (which seems to suggest it is OK to start here but it fails miserably):
http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosjava/Tutorials/Creating%20a%20ROS%20Android%20project

So, after some searching, I find and complete "Intalling rosjava_core":
http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/rosjava_core/html/installing.html
and then move onto "Building rosjava_core":
http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/rosjava_core/html/building.html
but get these errors, seem to be missing posedetection_msgs:

:rosjava_messages:compileJava
/home/dbarry/rosAndroid/rosjava_core/rosjava_messages/build/generated-src/siftviewer/ProcessImageCluster.java:19: package posedetection_msgs does not exist
java.util.List<posedetection_msgs.Feature0D> getFeatures();
^
/home/dbarry/rosAndroid/rosjava_core/rosjava_messages/build/generated-src/siftviewer/ProcessImageCluster.java:20: package posedetection_msgs does not exist
void setFeatures(java.util.List<posedetection_msgs.Feature0D> value);

Where do I get posedetection_msgs?

Bigger question-- is there an easier way to start using ROS Android?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33888/getting-started-with-ros-android:-error-in-building-rosjava_core/) by [dan](https://answers.ros.org/users/144/dan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 875 on 2012-05-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here is a partial answer.  Search for a while and find that posedetection_msgs is part of jsk-ros-pkg, see here:
http://ros.org/wiki/jsk-ros-pkg#jsk_android_apps
and download with svn:
svn co https://jsk-ros-pkg.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/jsk-ros-pkg/trunk
add the path to ROS_PACKAGE_PATH and then
rosmake posedetection_msgs

Then go back to rosAndroid and now
./gradlew install
works.

Unfortunately,
./gradlew tests
fails with these messages:
Test org.ros.internal.message.MessageSerializationTest FAILED
Test org.ros.time.NtpTimeProviderTest FAILED

> Building > :rosjava:test > 131 tests completed, 17 failures
> The test reports show the following details:
> java.util.NoSuchElementException: Resource does not exist: /std_msgs/msg/Bool.msg
> java.util.NoSuchElementException: Resource does not exist: /std_msgs/msg/Duration.msg
> .... many more similar.

but /opt/ros/fuerte/share/std_msgs/msg/Bool.msg does exist and
rospack find std_msgs
returns:
/opt/ros/fuerte/share/std_msgs

However, this still seems like a long walk for a short drink, so I suspect I am on the wrong path to just getting some ROS Android code to compile......

---

Originally posted by [dan](https://answers.ros.org/users/144/dan/) with karma: 875 on 2012-05-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) on 2012-05-24**:
I just pushed a fix for the failing tests.